# Asana Logging In Problems

Tags: asana

I can't log into Asana with my google account - Just get a 504 gateway timeout error.  Any advice?  I also can't register an account with a new email address.  Tried chrome and incognito window and asana app.

Comment: I had this same problem yesterday, "fixed" it by logging in using Firefox instead. Not sure what the Asana issue is though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for getting in contact! We were having some issues with availability through today (especially this morning), and our stability engineers are investigating the issue. We hope to be totally stable very shortly, and we recommend checking our status page at [trust.asana.com](https://trust.asana.com) for live status.

Sorry for the inconvenience, and thank you so much for your patience.